# R, read.* putting first column into row.names despite row.names=NULL directive

Tags: r

I have multiple batches of files delimited by tab to read in R. One variable though has an uncommon value "+" for each observation, the original data looks like this:

```
FileName  Elution   Sequence
f01.raw 10 +44.1DH
f01.raw 9 +44.1GH+57.0YR
f01.raw 6 +44.1VK+44.1AH+44.1K+44.1
f01.raw 9 +44.1DH
```

When I use the follow codes to read the file in R:

```
file01<-read.delim2("c:raw.data.PSM",header=TRUE,sep=c('\t'),quote="\"",row.names=NULL)
```

the data in R looks like as followed:

```
file01[1,]
row.names  FileName     Elution  Sequence
f01.raw     10    +44.1DH     NA
```

The row.names column is forced to BE name of the first variable of the original file, and all the variables thus are not attach to the right column. For example , the value "+44.1DH" is the Sequence but now is under elution column.

the first column has identical values throughout the file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with my copy of R (version 2.15.0).  I don't think this has anything to do with the `+` characters.  The behavior you describe sounds like `row.names=NULL` isn't doing what it's documented to do, which would be a bug in `read.table`.  What version do you have?

Comment: N.B. also I think you want `read.delim` not `read.delim2` as it appears that this data uses the Anglophone decimal point, not the Continental decimal comma.  And `sep='\t', quote='"', header=TRUE` are the default for `read.delim` and `read.delim2`.

Comment: I cannot replicate either. But i've assumed that all things that look like spaces in your sample are tabs. Are you sure that's the case? R will force there to be row.names when there is one fewer field in the header than in the first row of data. Perhaps use `head(count.fields("c:raw.data.PSM", sep="\t"))` to verify that the first few lines have the same number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command :

```
file01 <- read.table("test.txt", sep = "" , header = T , nrows = 100,
                   na.strings ="", stringsAsFactors= F)
```

result :

```
> file01[1,]
  FileName Elution Sequence
1  f01.raw      10  +44.1DH

View(file01)
```

[image]